# Designing and utilizing variable matrix in C

Tags: c

I am having some trouble designing a matrix in my project. How would you define a variable matrix? I am using an LED Matrix for a connect four game using HCS12 Dragon 12 Light, and I want to define a matrix that allows me to light up the board. How do I define a variable matrix [8]x[8] with rows x columns? Furthermore, how might I call certain points of this matrix in other functions like if else statements? Thanks for any responses

To clarify further, I am just wondering about syntax. I want to define an 8x8 matrix 2D array that is variable based on the game results. Furthermore, I am wondering how I would be able to call certain entries in the matrix in functions and statements

Comment: You should show your attempt thus far, as well as what your pinouts are and if you are using any frameworks like arduino/teensyduino. In general, you will need some function which can "pump out" the matrix to the game board.

Comment: Use a matrix that will allow you to implement the game logic, regardless of how you intend to display the game. Always separate 'form' from 'function'. Then you can use the same game engine, whatever display method you chose.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a "variable matrix"? Do you mean a two-dimensional array where number of rows/columns ar not known at compile-time? Or do you mean to define a variable that holds an 8x8 array?

Comment: @HAL9000 I mean a 2D array that relies on the results from the moves of the game. Thats what I mean by variable matrix.

Comment: What is wrong with `int board[8][8];`?

Comment: @HAL9000 How do I call it so I map the row and columns in the array? I use row and column both as int. I am trying to make an if-else statement that relies on certain locations in the matrix. How do I call a certain entry in the matrix in a statement like that?

Comment: You can treat the initial index as the row, and the second as the column (and vice-versa) via `board[row][column]`. This will retrieve (or allow you to set) the associated `int` at those indices.

Comment: Do you have problem referencing elements in an array? (Getting and setting their value.) If that is the case, it is time to get a good tutorial. C is a powerful language, but it is difficult to learn without appropriate literature.

Comment: If the 8x8 matrix contains a simple "flag" data (on/off), than a `uint64_t` could hold all the data as a bitmap (`bit = (row*8) + column`)... fairly simple to access, set and unset the data.